# Correct way to track paycheck deductions when using personal finance sites?

Tags: united-states, budget, online-tools, deduction

I have been using mint.com and personalcapital.com for a while now and was wondering how do you track things like health insurance, 401k deductions, and your real income (before deductions).

Mint.com for example only sees the deposit to my checking account and doesn't know that I actually earned more and had to pay deductions.

Looking at my budget it looks like I don't pay for things like 401k and health insurance. Would be nice to see the complete picture on what is going on so I can see what actually happened.

Comment: I don't know Mint so this is not an answer.  I added the 401k account to my personal finance application.  When money gets added to the 401k account, I record the other side of the transaction as being part of the same category I record my paycheck income in.  Is something like that possible in Mint?

Comment: I'd argue they don't really play into your budget, what matters is the money you have to spend, and 401k / deductions aren't part of that equation, so some of those tools might not support tracking them at all.

Comment: @HartCO But the choice of how much to put into a 401k etc. is as much a budget decision as how much to allow yourself for eating out etc.. And while it would probably be foolish to _cut_ what you put in a 401k to have more to spend on eating out, if you're lucky (careful?) enough to have a surpluses, having visibility of the 401k may nudge you into increasing the 401k.

Comment: I guess this is more of transparency and visibility to see everything in your budget. By default mint.com doesn't know about my saving to retirement or my health insurance co-pay. 

@Eric I think has the best idea. By adding the transactions for my 401K contribution (or the software adding it for me), and adding the deduction I can see that I did pay into it and how much I earned and contributed. 

For health care it is the same method, but since there is no health care account you have to do both the addition and subtraction. 

Next question is how to make it automated?